# php Проблема сортировки масива по Укр алфавиту

Tags: php, laravel

Есть масив, сортирую по алфавиту,русский сортируется правильно а вот украинский почти правильно,кроме буквы "І" она ставится на первое место в сортировке.Как отсортировать масив по Укр алфавиту?

```
  public function findCountries()
{
    $countries = Country::whereHas('store')->withTranslation()->get();
    $all_country = [];
    foreach ($countries as $county) {
        $all_country[] =
            [
                'id' => $county->id,
                'code' => $county->code,
                'name' => $county->name,
            ];
    }
    function build_sorter($key)
    {
        return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
            return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
        };
    }

    usort($all_country, build_sorter('name'));
    
    return response()->json(['countries' => $all_country]);
}
```

[Вот так выглядит готовый список,видно что страна с названием которое начинается на букву I на первом месте](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwymE.png)[image: А вот дамп масива]

Comment: потому что strnatcmp сравнивает просто строки. И она не знает о алфавитах. Используйте правильные функции. Например, [strcoll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcoll.php) и подобные, перед этим корректно выставив локаль. Но даже в этом случае нужно быть осторожным.

Comment: Повелосипедить, Сваять свою ф-цию сортировки.

Comment: Установил локаль таким образом setlocale (LC_COLLATE, 'uk_UA'); использовал функцию strcoll но результат тотже.
Проверил доступние локали и в списке нету украинской или русской локали                      
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX

Comment: Значит нужно добавить локаль в систему `apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales; sed -i 's/^# *(ru_RU.UTF-8)/\1/' /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen` только поменяйте русскую на ua

Comment: Спасибо, это важная информация, пускай будет, еще пригодится. А саму сортировку решил выборкой с базы с помощью самого пакета переводов

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с этой проблемой. Рекомендую использовать Collator:

```
usort($array, function($item_1, $item_2) {
    $collator = collator_create('uk_UA');
    $arr = array($item_1['name'], $item_2['name']);
    collator_asort($collator, $arr, Collator::SORT_STRING);

    return array_pop($arr) == $item_1['name'];
});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

Нужно делать через collator (create, asort)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).